# If i share an unsigned XCARCHIVE file with a client, can they see the source code?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

If i share an unsigned XCARCHIVE file with a client, can they see the source code? Is it in any way less secure than sending them the IPA file?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you take a look inside an .xcarchive, you'll see that it consists of a "dSYM" directory (which holds the debug symbols for the application), an Info.plist, and a directory containing the application binary. It should be no less secure than sending an IPA.

Comment: Sounds fair enough. I had a look in the app binary with a hex editor - didn't see any readable code, but i did find a bunch of selector names - these wouldn't be decompilable would they?

Comment: I'm afraid that is beyond my area of expertise. If I may ask, what's the worst a client could do with the names of your methods?

Comment: @MarkAdams: Reverse engineer the app so the OP's work becomes effectively valueless to them and he loses both their business AND his IP?

Comment: Anyone who could reverse engineer all the functionality of an app based on method names alone totally deserves it.

Comment: @Chris: If you run the `strings` utility in Linux on the application binary, you can see all of the literal `NSString` values you have written in the source code as well.

Comment: @MarkAdams: Software development isn't just being able to write methods that do X, it's also about designing the application flow and properly modularising the code. So the OP does in fact lose some IP if the client can clearly see the design/flow.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I think you're being a tad pedantic. I could design an amusement park with the same layout and names of places as Disneyland, but that wouldn't make it Disneyland. It's all in the details.

Comment: Signing it doesn't make a user unable to poke about inside the app bundle, it just means they can't change something and expect it to work on a non-jailbroken device.

Comment: So, judging by what wevah says, there's no added security by going to an IPA over an XCARCHIVE, since the only addition is the signature. Makes sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

Distributing a .xcarchive directory is a bad idea if you are worried about reverse engineering.

Specifically a .ipa file typically does not contain the C symbol table.

Any mach-o binary linked against any objc will include segments which describe all of the objc classes, selectors and imp addresses.  This is great to have when reversing, but the C symbol table is something that can and should be discarded from your distributed binary.

The .dSYM dir (containing the stripped symbol table) is kept specifically so that stack traces in crash reports can be symbolicated.  There is no techinal reason to distribute it.

Indeed, to the reverse-engineer, having the symbol table can be priceless.

If you are worried about someone reverse engineering some of your logic, implement everything with private C functions (all in the same file as far as the compiler is concerned) and distribute a stripped binary only (.ipa not .xcarchive).

Don't use objc any more than you are forced to.

Even then, someone who is good with a decompiler will still figure it all out eventually, but it will be a lot harder.